# Is there a way to run Cossacks Back To War on Windows 8.1 without virtual machine? (mouse problem)

Tags: technical-issues, cossacks-back-to-war

I have the mouse problem which has become famous under Cossacks players who play in Windows Vista or up. This problem is that I can't move the mouse within the game. I tried everything available on the internet:

- 2 patches
- set my compatibility settings to all versions from XP down to 95
- tried reducing my screen resolution.

Is there another way to do it? I don't want to set up a virtual box because it is very technical work which I don't want to try. Anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: The only way I found to make it work was to buy the steam version and to run it with steam in admin mode.

Comment: How much does it cost?

Comment: BTW does anybody know if it runs vista, I have a laptop which is curently empty of battery and the charger is broken but if i get a new one i might throw it on there, anybody knows if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Download Cossacks Anthology [GOG] and it works fine. I am using with Windows 8.1. If that doesn't help download this patch http://www.gsc-game.com/index.php?t=downloads&ss=299&s=patch and follow the instructions inside.

Comment: the patch didn't work, can you tel me clearly how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Cossacks 3 is out, and it fixes this problem.

It's very much like cossacks 1, except much more beautiful.